# Is Code Coverage Plugin still available in NetBeans 7.0? How can I use it?

Tags: java, netbeans, code-coverage

I've been searching on the internet on tutorials of code coverage test in NetBeans.
However, most tutorials use a plugin called NetBeans Code Coverage Plugin, which should be found in the 'Available Plugins'. However, it's not there.
So, how can I test Java code coverage in NetBeans 7.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find both `Cobertura Module Test Coverage` and `Maven Test Coverage` in Available Plugins. You should choose one according to your build tool.

Have a look at this link for more info:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenCodeCoverage

Answer (score 5):

Following link will navigate to you at NetBeans Code Coverage Plugins.

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38945/unit-tests-code-coverage-plugin-updated-for-netbeans-7-0

Comment: Thank you. This plugin was added on "2011-05-10" according to that page. It appears that I was quite unlucky as I tried to search for this on Apr 28 '11 and asked a question here subsequently. I don't need it anymore. But thank you anyway.